# How to convert base 64 string to bitmap in android using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

As per my requirement, from the API response I am getting the base 64 string. I need to convert that to bitmap in kotlin android. So for that after going through some samples in stackoverflow and google I tried the below way:

```
    Code:
    
       class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LogInHandler {

    private lateinit var viewModel: LogInViewModel
private lateinit var imageVieww : ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
imageVieww = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageVieww)
        // Binding
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityLoginBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_login)
        // ViewModel
        this.viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LogInViewModel::class.java)
        // Setting binding params
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.handler = this
        // Watching for login result
        viewModel.getLogInResult().observe(this, Observer { result ->
            Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })

        var imageBinary = "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"
        val imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageBinary.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
        val decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
        println("check decoded image size:+${decodedImage.byteCount}")
        imageVieww.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedImage, 120, 120, false))

    }

    override fun onLogInClicked() {
        viewModel.performValidation()
    }

}
xml:
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.samplekotlinapplication.LogInViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.example.samplekotlinapplication.LogInHandler" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".LogInActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/label_login"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/et_username"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_username"
            android:text="@={viewModel.username}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/et_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_login"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_login"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_login" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="@={viewModel.password}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageVieww"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/et_username"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/et_username"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_username" />

        <!--    <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{()->handler.onLogInClicked()}"
            android:text="@string/action_login"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/et_password"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/et_password"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_password" />-->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageVieww"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_password" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But the image is not showing on the UI when I run the application. I am not getting what is wrong in this code. Can anybody please help me with this as I am stuck here.

Comment: I tested your code with different base64 string it is working for me. Might be issue with your base64 image string. Try your code with some online test image string and verify it.

Comment: Hi, could you please send base 64 string which you checked..i tried some online images strings..its not working for me :(

Comment: from the following link I tried https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/Xadvz/

Comment: Hi, I tried the base 64 string which you provided... it's still not loading on the image view for me..not getting where was the issue for me :(

Comment: one more suggestion,you can atleast before setting bitmap to imageview check the size of the image view decodedImage.byteCount if its > 0 string is getting decodes so issue should not be with decoding, try adding some static image to your imageview is it actually showing any image or not. still does not work share your source code to under stand better.

Comment: Hi I checked the size now..it is showing decoded image size:+4148, and I added a static image to the image view..it is showing..but the image from the decoded string is not showing

Comment: added my complete code..can you check

Comment: `I checked the size now..it is showing decoded image size:+4148,` And what was the original size? Before you encoded to base64?

Comment: `var imageBinary = "R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJos....` That would better be called `var imagebas64 = "R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJos`. And how did you place that string in your code? How did you obtain that string? From where exactly?

Comment: I have given println("check imagebytes size:+${imageBytes.size}") and the size is size:+1951

Comment: I got that string from jsfiddle.net/casiano/Xadvz but in my project, I will be getting the string from the API response

Comment: Hi All, I created a new emulator (PIXEL XL API 28) and executed the app..it worked perfectly, and am able to see the image on UI finally :). I think its the device or the emulator issue.